# Remove random text from filename based on list

Tags: python

So I have a list of files from glob that are formated in the following way

```
filename xx xxx moretxt.txt
```

what I'am trying to do is rename them as follows

```
filename.txt
```

the first two xx is one of these:

```
[1B, 2B, 3B, 4B, 5B, 6B, 7B, 8B, 9B, 10B, 11B, 12B, 1A, 2A, 3A, 4A, 5A, 6A, 7A, 8A, 9A, 10A, 11A, 12A]
```

so how do I remove the "xx xxx moretxt" from the file name and keep the extension?

```
import glob, os
os.chdir("C:\\somepath")

for file in glob.glob("**/*.txt", recursive = True):
    print(file)
```

Comment: You could try capturing only the first word with regex.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't simply `split()` the filename and take the first item (which would be `'filename'`)? The terms are space separated already. Similarly, `split('.')[-1]` for the extension itself.

Comment: Do you know how the file names start? Is it always the string `"filename"`? Is it of a fiex length? Do they always have the same file extension?

Comment: The filename should not have spaces/uppercase/integer characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `str.split`

**Ex:**

```
filename = "filename xx xxx moretxt.txt"
val = filename.split()
filename = "{}.{}".format(val[0], val[-1].split(".")[-1])
print(filename)
```

---

or using `re.match`

**Ex:**

```
import re

filename = "filename xx xxx moretxt.txt"

filename = re.match(r"(?P<filename>\w+).*\.(?P<ext>.+)", filename)
filename = "{}.{}".format(filename.group('filename'), filename.group('ext'))
print(filename)
```

**Output:**

```
filename.txt
```

Comment: sorry should have specifed that the filename is unique for each file not just "filename" but eg "screw12323 2b 100.txt" or boltandnot 12b 125" hence the array

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand.

Comment: "screw12323 2b 100.txt"  should be renamed to "screw12323.txt", 
"boltandnot 12b 125.txt" should be renamed to "boltandnots.txt" and so on :)

Comment: The above should work for this also...did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

When I try this, I only get one filename..

```
import re  
import glob, os  
os.chdir("C:\\Somepath")  

for filename in glob.glob("**/*.txt", recursive = True):  
    filename = re.match(r"(?P<filename>\w+).*\.(?P<ext>.+)", filename)  
    filename = "{}.{}".format(filename.group('filename'), filename.group('ext'))  
    print(filename)
```

output:
screw12323.txt
screw12323.txt
screw12323.txt
screw12323.txt
screw12323.txt '