# Renaming mp3 files with random ending in filename

Tags: python

I have a folder with files named like this "artist - track XX XXX.mp3"
what I'am trying to do is have the files renamed to just "artist - track.mp3"

the last part of the file will always begin one of these:
[1B, 2B, 3B, 4B, 5B, 6B, 7B, 8B, 9B, 10B, 11B, 12B, 1A, 2A, 3A, 4A, 5A, 6A, 7A, 8A, 9A, 10A, 11A, 12A]

so how do I remove the "XX XXX" and keep the rest?

```
import re, glob, os

os.chdir("C:\\Somepath")

for filename in glob.glob("**/*.mp3", recursive = True):
    filename = re.match(r"(?P<filename>\w+).*\.(?P<ext>.+)", filename)
    filename = "{}.{}".format(filename.group('filename'), filename.group('ext'))
    print(filename)
```

which just outputs only the first artistname from the first file:
artist.mp3
artist.mp3
artist.mp3

What is the rest that I am missing here, simply can't figure out how to solve this..

Comment: If you figured out how to create a regex with two named groups, you can figure out how to create one with three named groups, no?

Comment: The regex in your question was for your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56444243/remove-random-text-from-filename-based-on-list#comment99482015_56444243). Obviously the exact same thing wouldn't work for a different pattern. Could you show what _you_ have tried in the interim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regexp group matching the filename only allows word (`\w`) characters, so it stops at the first space. Instead of

```
filename = re.match(r"(?P<filename>\w+).*\.(?P<ext>.+)", filename)
```

try

```
filename = re.match(r"(?P<filename>.+)\s+\d{1,2}[AB].*\.(?P<ext>.+)", filename)
```

This will make the filename group match everything up to the first "XX". The latter consists of whitespace followed by one or two digits followed by `A` or `B`.

Comment: That made everything a hold lot better, but I get a error, the output is correct but after the last file I get: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\E\Scripts\mp3handler.py", line 10, in <module>
    filename = "{}.{}".format(filename.group('filename'), filename.group('ext'))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @Gromit It sounds like `re.match(...)` returned `None`, which means the filename didn't match the expected pattern.

Comment: that sounds about right, thanks for your help and clue back to google and try to solve this :)

Comment: @Gromit Actually since your filenames are coming from `glob.glob()`, it's probably not a blank line. Try printing out the filename for debugging purposes *before* you start the regexp matching.

Comment: sorry my mistake there was a folder in the folder I had forgotten and that contained a mp3 that didn't have the XX XXX.mp3 ending thats why it failed.. got a pointer or a clue to how I can make and exception if it doesn't have it?

Comment: @Gromit: Follow your `re.match` line with a conditional: `if filename is not None:` and put the next two lines inside that conditional. That way, if a filename doesn't match the pattern, your script will do nothing with it.